# How to change the default language in OpenCart 3.0.3?

Tags: opencart-3

I have added a new language in OpenCart. But I can't find where to change the default language for the admin panel.
[picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz3rwz2n27ai761/language.JPG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply open the store settings (backend > System >> Settings >>> Choose your store) and click on **Locales** tab.
There change the language under **Admin Language**.